# KDE Plasma Panel Changes not Saving

Tags: ubuntu, kde, settings, plasma, panel

I install KDE Plasma and when I change something in panel like adding new widgets or removing widgets, all changes that I made dissappears when I reboot my computer.

Comment: Do you see any traces of a read-only filesystem in dmesg or syslog? Do other operations work fine when changing files?

Comment: No I don't see, there is no errors showing up but when rebooting my computer or just logging off refreshes it and everything gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I had this problem on my Debian 11 (bullseye) a few days ago,
I found out that my **/home/user/.cache** folder was filling up rapidly (mounting video on KDEnLive), and as it occurs my **/home** partition was filling up.

Just in case you didn't check,
run a :

```bsh
(sudo) df -h
```

worth the ckeck.

Comment: Nice! Thanks Fabs!